# How do I get the workaddress shown in Google contacts for an google account using .Net and API

Tags: .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

When I add contact info for an account, I do not see the work address shown in google contacts.
What setting am I missing?

I use the Directory API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert
I am using NuGet package 1.9.0.490

www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/

I create an user, and set his contact info.
But when I lookup the account in google contacts I do not see the address info.

```
List<UserAddress> newAddresses = new List<UserAddress>();
UserAddress newAddress = new UserAddress
    {
        Country = "Netherlands",
        CountryCode = "NL",
        Type = "work", 
        ExtendedAddress = "address extension",  // just for demo
        Locality = "amsterdam",
        PoBox = "Postbus 1000", // just for demo
        PostalCode = "1000 AA",
        Primary = true,
        Region = "Noord-Holland",  // just for demo
        StreetAddress = "Main street 1"
    };
newAddresses.Add(newAddress);
User newUser = new User
    {
        Name = "Demo User",
        PrimaryEmail = "demo.user@domain.com",
        Addresses = newAddresses,
        ChangePasswordAtNextLogin = true,
        Password = "*****",
        IncludeInGlobalAddressList = true,
        IpWhitelisted = true,
        OrgUnitPath = @"/User/Demo/",
        AgreedToTerms = true,
        IsMailboxSetup = true
    };

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"\location\P12File.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
IEnumerable<string> scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserSecurity };
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("ServiceAccountEmail@domain.com")
    {
        Scopes = scopes,
        User = "AdminAccount@domain.com"
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new DirectoryService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Admin directory Provisioning Sample",
    });
service.Users.Insert(newUser).Execute();
```

When I retrieve the user by code I can see that the information is stored:

```
> +     Addresses   {[   {
>     "type": "work",
>     "poBox": "Postbus 1000",
>     "extendedAddress": "address extension",
>     "streetAddress": "Main street 1",
>     "locality": "amsterdam",
>     "region": "Noord-Holland",
>     "postalCode": "1000 AA",
>     "country": "Netherlands",
>     "primary": true,
>     "countryCode": "NL"   } ]}    object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray}
```

I have an image example of contacts data:

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6t050r4NXnDM2pUTjJoY0ZHMVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How long after running your code did you check the Directory Profile? Contact information in the Directory updates every 24 hours (https://support.google.com/a/answer/1628009). Because of this, if it hasn't been a least a day since you updated the profile, it's expected that it might not be displaying.

Comment: Hi I know about 25 hour timeframe, so before I posted the question I already waited at least 36 hours.And I checked this mornimg, still no address

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting my addresses to display as well. After working with support, the solution was to also update the "formatted" attribute with whatever you want displayed for their address. This doesn't appear to be documented.

Example:

```
{
  "type":"work", 
  "formatted":"123 Nowhere Somewhereville MN 55555", 
  "streetAddress":"123 Nowhere",
  "locality":"Somewhereville", 
  "region":"MN", 
  "postalCode":"55555"
}
```